# wsdl2objc is not working on ios 6.0 simulator but works on ios 5 device

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap, ios6, wsdl2objc

I am using wsdl2objc generated stub to interact with my soap service, everything is fine when i run the app on a device running iOS 5.But when I run the same app on the simulator (iOS 6) i see that no request is sent (debugged using fiddler).

I tried by putting break points on the following code :

```
- (DeptServiceImplPortBindingResponse *)performSynchronousOperation:(DeptServiceImplPortBindingOperation *)operation
{
    synchronousOperationComplete = NO;
[operation start];

    // Now wait for response
    NSRunLoop *theRL = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]; //breakpoint1 

    while (!synchronousOperationComplete && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]); //breakpoint2 
    return operation.response; // breakpoint 3
}
```

The control never reaches breakpoint 3 that means that the synchronous operation did not complete.

Any inputs on how to go about solving the problem ? would be great help.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it , the problem was with the https authentication , since i have the certificate installed on my device it was going through.